# How to Using Oracle client OO4O in VB6

Tags: vb6, oracle10g

I have an vb6 application working using Oracle 10g which uses oo4o to connect with database.
Oracle 10g is installed on remote Database server.
But i don't know how to setting on client PC to run vb6 application.
(When I run it, it shows error msg "ora-12154 tns could not resolve service name")

Please help me the way (step by step) to setting on client PC to vb6 application can be connected to oracle database.

Regards

Comment: The first thing I would do is verify your connection string.  Here is a [good reference](https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/) to get you started.

Comment: Edit the question to add the relevant code, otherwise its too unclear